# Solaris 10: Latex post-installation error, looking for old libstdc++.so.5

Tags: latex, solaris

I am trying to run Latex on Solaris 10/x86. I have successfully installed the tetex3.0 from sunfree. When I run Latex I get the following error:

ld.so.1: pdfetex: fatal: libstdc++.so.5: open failed: No such file or directory

and ldd pdfetex shows:

libstdc++.so.5 =>        (file not found)

I have the latest version (libstdc++.so.6) and tried to link libstdc++.so.5 to .6 however, the libstdc++.so.5 is not even installed in my machine. Is there a way to change the dependency from version 5 to 6? Or any other way around this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed [their note](http://sunfreeware.com/programlistintel10.html#tetex) stating that

> [..] that you have the /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so.5 and /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 related files either from the gcc-3.3.2 or libgcc-3.3 or higher packages

Did you install `[lib]gcc` as well?

Comment: Yes, I did install the packagae libgcc-3.4.6 which has libstdc++.so.6. Should I also install libgcc-3.3? Will that pose compatible issues between the two versions with other packages that use libgcc?

Comment: @ShuvoShams Installing them should be fine, usually gcc-packages live in their own namespaces. If there is a conflict, the package system should tell you.